# Dataframe: get_dummies for arrays in coll

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Working with Python/Pandas

I have a csv file pretty simple except for one column: the source is an array.

An example of my table:

```
Column A                  |Column B  |Column C  |Column D  |  
__________________________|__________|__________|__________|
[Water, Food, Groceries]  |  0       |true      |9         |
[Water, Desert, Sand]     |  1       |false     |1         |
[Earth, Groceries]        |  2       |null      |12        |
[Air, Food, Car]          |  3       |true      |8         |
[Cristal, Love, Groceries]|  4       |false     |0         |
```

What I want to accomplish:

```
Column B  |Column C  |Column D  |column_a_water |column_a_food  | column_a_groceries |
__________|__________|__________|_______________|_______________|____________________|
  0       |true      |9         |  1            |  1            |  1                 |
  1       |false     |1         |  1            |  0            |  0                 |
  2       |null      |12        |  0            |  0            |  1                 |
  3       |true      |8         |  0            |  1            |  0                 |
  4       |false     |0         |  0            |  0            |  1                 |
```

With pandas get_dummies I can make it work with Column C, but not with Column A. Using the same technique it does not work.

What can I do to deal with this situation?

Comment: Does column A contains `list` of `strings` or simple `string`?

Comment: Hey! Always a list with values repeating sometimes.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use, [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) on `Column A`, then use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) on this exploded column then use [`DataFrame.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) on `level=0` then using [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) add prefix `Column A` to each of the dummy columns, finally using [`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) join the the original dataframe with the dataframe containing dummy columns:

```
# Use this line IF the values in Column A are type of `string` instead of lists.
df['Column A'] = df['Column A'].str.strip('[]').str.split('\s*,\s*')

df1 = (
    df['Column A'].explode()
    .str.get_dummies().sum(level=0).add_prefix('Column A_')
)

df1 = df.drop('Column A', 1).join(df1)
```

Result:

```
# print(df1)

   Column B Column C  Column D  Column A_Air  ...  Column A_Groceries  Column A_Love  Column A_Sand  Column A_Water
0         0     True         9             0  ...                   1              0              0               1
1         1    False         1             0  ...                   0              0              1               1
2         2      NaN        12             0  ...                   1              0              0               0
3         3     True         8             1  ...                   0              0              0               0
4         4    False         0             0  ...                   1              1              0               0
```

Comment: I like the way you think, but using the exactly your answer I get the same result: Colum_A_ ['Water', 'Oblivious', 'Cooking'] and not like yours. Did I miss something?

Comment: Then i guess your Column A don't contain the values as arrays, they are simple strings enclosed in `[]`, First we need to convert them to lists.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what Shubham has, just slightly different way of writing it,

```
ohe = pd.get_dummies(df['Column A'].explode())
result = pd.concat([df, ohe.groupby(level=0).sum()], axis=1).drop('Column A', axis=1)
```